# Why can't you start ufw on wsl2?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, ufw

***I have this error. I have days trying to solve it but I can not find the answer, if someone something similar happened I would appreciate your help.***

ERROR: problem running ufw-init
iptables-restore v1.8.4 (legacy): Couldn't load match `limit':No such file or directory

Error occurred at line: 63
Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information. iptables-restore v1.8.4 (legacy): Couldn't load match` limit':No such file or directory

Error occurred at line: 8
Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.

Problem running '/etc/ufw/before.rules'
Problem running '/etc/ufw/user.rules'

[ERROR: problem running ufw-init](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qV5Tr.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please be aware that one of the main criteria for questions on this site is that they be regarding *"specific coding, algorithm, or language problems."* Your question would likely be better suited for [Super User](https://superuser.com) or (more likely) [Unix & Linux Stack](https://unix.stackoverflow.com), but please be sure to familiarize yourself with those sites' rules for posting as well.  I'd recommend deleting it here and moving it over to one of the other sites before the mods close it.  It won't count "against" your rep if you do it yourself before downvotes.

Comment: Also recommend adding what distribution you are using, along with some of the things you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

Adding a firewall to wsl2 might not be very useful because you can gain root access to wsl2 with a simple command: "wsl -u root".

Check this (https://superuser.com/a/1626513) post out for more details.